# Python code(boto3) insert SQL to table in AWS Glue data catalog

Tags: pyspark, boto3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark

Task - I have to insert some data into table which reside in AWS Glue data catalog.

I use boto3 to retrieve the data from table already but i can't write to glue catalog.

```
client = boto3.client('glue', 'us-east-1')
client.put_item(tablename = 'abcd', item={'col1':{'S','goal'},'col2':{'S','goal1'})
job.commit()
```

got an error

```
 glue object has no attribute 'put_item'
```

Question - How to insert data into table in AWS Glue data catalog.
Please help!

Comment: Glue Data catalog does not store any actual data. Its a metadata which stores information about your data. Not sure what do you really want to do?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue does not have a putItem method - see here for
[Boto3 Glue documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html). While invalid, it appears your code should be used for DynamoDB given the reference to the method name, and parameters (e.g. table, item).